# CRM Plugin not working C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm

I am making a plugin that is supposed to take data from `Quote Product` entity.
By default, there is no discount in percent field, just discount amount. I added Discount% filed to the form (`ad_discountpercent`). Now I should calculate new price like this:

```
sum = (price - discount)*quantity*(100 - discount%)/100
```

I made a code for that. When i build this code there are no errors, but there are no changes in the CRM. I have also registered my plugin.

There are 3 fields `manualdiscountamount` , `priceperunit` , `extendedamount` that are Currency type fields. `quantity` is decimal and `ad_discountpercent` is integer. I have found a few methods for getting value from Currency, some are commented, some are not, because I don't know which one is proper.

One notice i checked fetch results, and they are as expected, so fetch is working fine. I compressed it in one line, because of the code length.

Here is the part of the code that should do the job. I have no information is there anything wrong with conversion, am I using proper way to set a new value?
I am new in this, so any comment would help me.

```
string fetch1 = @"<fetch count='50' ><entity name='quotedetail' ><attribute name='manualdiscountamount' /><attribute name='priceperunit' /><attribute name='ad_discountpercent' /><attribute name='quantity' /> <attribute name='extendedamount' /> <filter> <condition attribute='ad_discountpercent' operator='not-null'/>   </filter >  </ entity>            </fetch>";            

EntityCollection result = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetch1));

foreach (var c in result.Entities)
{           
    // int discountPer = (int)c.Attributes["ad_discountpercent"];
    int discountPer = c.GetAttributeValue<int>("ad_discountpercent");

    Money m = (Money)c.Attributes["priceperunit"];
    decimal price = m.Value;
    // decimal price = c.GetAttributeValue<decimal>("priceperunit");

    Money m1 = (Money)c.Attributes["manualdiscountamount"];
    decimal discount = m1.Value;
    // decimal discount = c.GetAttributeValue<decimal>("manualdiscountamount");

    //decimal discountPer = Convert.ToDecimal( c.Attributes["ad_discountpercent"]);

    decimal quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(c.Attributes["quantity"]);
    //decimal quantity = c.GetAttributeValue<decimal>("quantity");

    decimal sum = (price - discount) * quantity * (100 - discountPer) / 100;

    Money summTotal = new Money();
    summTotal.Value = sum;
    entity["extendedamount"] = summTotal;
    service.Update(entity);
```

Comment: Where do you get the `entity` into which you store the result? Also, on which step did you register the plugin (on "Update" of "QuoteProduct")? Here is a walk-trough on how to debug a plugin: [Step by Step: Working with CRM2011 plugin profiler](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2778280)

Comment: This is just a part of the code, there is a part before where i get my entity.I will try to debug this plugin.

Comment: If you have the right entity, your way of updating the value should work (note that you update the same entity multiple times). Did you verify that your plugin is registered for the correct step? After you start profiling the plugin, you should see an error message when you trigger the plugin from CRM.

Comment: I also see there is probably a problem with step registration. I will try to throw an exception to see weather plugin is triggered or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ExtendedAmount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt593069.aspx) is an auto-calculated field based on `priceperunit` and `quantity`. So any updates to this field will be ignored by CRM.

Instead update the `priceperunit` and `quantity` to get the desired `extendedamount`.

```
entity["priceperunit"] = new Money((price - discount) * quantity * (100 - discountPer) / 100);
entity["quantity"] = 1;
service.Update(entity);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that your query isn't returning any data, therefore your loop is never dropped into and your update never executes?

As previously suggested, take a look at how to debug a plugin via the plugin profiler.

Or, if you don't want to do that. Throw an temporary exception in your code after you do the RetrieveMultiple and in the message, add in the result.Entities.Count value to confirm how many records you're getting back.

Comment: I made the same fetch in JavaScript, and putted in on form, and there are 4 lines of results.